# Error on redirecting a Page

Tags: javascript, php

Sorry, I am new to Coding.

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>ajaman.php";
```

The Above Code just Prints the URL from Ajaman.php instead of Opening it..!! How to directly **open** it ?

Comment: Is this inside a `<script>` tag?

Comment: yes..!! it's inside script Tag only..!! Please help

Comment: try `window.location.replace("<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>ajaman.php");` instead. [`read more`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/2518525)

Comment: Please view your browser page source, and copy the code that gets rendered there in the `<script>` tag after the PHP executes.  Edit and paste it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(window).load(function() {
window.location.href ="<?=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>/ajaman.php";
});
```

the php tags inside the js script will only work in php pages. Not work in .js files.